# как устранить ошибку записи в файл?

Tags: c#

Есть функция,которая записывает переданное ей булевое значение в файл.

```
     private void WriteBool(bool valueToWrite)//запись флага
    {
        FileInfo fileToWrite = new FileInfo("progress.txt");

        if (!fileToWrite.Exists)
        {
            //Create a file to write to.
            using (StreamWriter sw = fileToWrite.CreateText())
            {
                sw.WriteLine(valueToWrite);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("progress.txt");
            writer.WriteLine(valueToWrite);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

по-идее,код должен покидать эту функцию после выполнения оператора `writer.Close()`,но при пошаговой отладке код покидает функцию после оператора`StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("progress.txt");
Стек трейс:
System.IO.IOException: Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "D:\Users\dave\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MailSending\MailSending\bin\Debug\progress.txt", так как этот файл используется другим процессом.

в System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

в System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)

в System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)

в System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)

в System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
как определить процесс,который использует файл?

Comment: Файл в этот момент на диске присутствует?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов,роль этой

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов функции в программе-изменение значение флага,заранее записанного в файл.как вы видите,в самой функции есть проверка существования файла

Comment: Раз файл уже есть, проблема может быть в том, что вы пытаетесь открыть уже открытый файл. И второй вариант - попытка вызова CreateFile с флагом CREATE_NEW где-то в недрах рантайма.

Comment: > как определить процесс,который использует файл? -- обновил свой ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Весь ваш код заменяется одной строкой:

```
private void WriteBool(bool valueToWrite)//запись флага
{
    File.WriteAllText("progress.txt", valueToWrite.ToString());
}
```

Чтобы посмотреть, каким процессом занят файл, скачайте [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), в нем нажмите Ctrl+F и укажите название файла.

Comment: И где тут обработка ошибок?